# How do I make bootstrap's container take into account absolute divs that exist with the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's [container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) has great built in breakpoints that scale a div to match the width of the page. However on my page I have a absolute positioned div that sits on the side of the page. The container does not take into consideration this absolutely positioned div, and expands to be under the div at all times (unless the width of the browser is very large).

How can I tell Bootstrap's container to only consider a certain percentage of the browser width to accommodate my absolute div, while still being responsive? Putting the container inside a smaller div breaks the grid layout of Bootstrap and the container is no longer responsive.

Example:

**Good: The browser is wide enough, static div sits properly to the right**

[image: Good example]

**Bad: Container has hit several breakpoints and shrunk down. Static div now overtakes container.**

[image: Bad example]

Comment: make a container with 2 columns. 1st for your main content, 2nd for your side content

Answer (score 0):

Container adjust size to fit their container.
Assume as you use container in the body tag.
Add the padding-right to body tag same size as your absolute box.

```
<body style="padding-right: {your_absolute_box_size}px;">

or

body { padding-right: {your_absolute_box_size}px; }
```